# Best ways to record data on interference pattern using Tektronix DPO 5204B oscilloscope?

Tags: measurements, interference

I am looking at an interference pattern signal using a Tektronix DPO 5204B oscilloscope which has windows 7 and TekScope software. This interference pattern grows and shrinks with time (approximately 10-20 seconds for the full cycle). It is my intention to measure the maximum pk-pk voltage and the minimum pk-pk voltage of this cycle without using cursors. The goal is automation of the data acquisition process so that I could perhaps press the SINGLE button and collect data over a small timeframe that contains this interference variation cycle.

Does anybody know a good method(s) to obtain a measurement like this using a similar oscilloscope?

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/test-measurement/oscilloscopes/mso5000-dpo5000-series-dpo5204/manual/

Comment: I have that manual next to me right now but my capability with this instrument is too limited to understand the best options for this type of measurement.